# Openconnect VPN script bash formatting error

Tags: bash, openvpn

Im trying to get openconnect vpn client on mac osx to use this default script, but im getting the following error.

> /etc/vpnc/vpnc-script: line 730: syntax error: unexpected end of file
> Script '/etc/vpnc/vpnc-script' returned error 2

I was getting a similar error before following a post explaining to use this formatting which I copy pasted exactly. I then ran chmod 777 on the file to give make it executable.

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
#!/bin/sh
# List of parameters passed through environment
#* reason                       -- why this script was called, one of: pre-init connect disconnect
#* VPNGATEWAY                   -- vpn gateway address (always present)
#* TUNDEV                       -- tunnel device (always present)
#* INTERNAL_IP4_ADDRESS         -- address (always present)
#* INTERNAL_IP4_MTU             -- mtu (often unset)
#* INTERNAL_IP4_NETMASK         -- netmask (often unset)
#* INTERNAL_IP4_NETMASKLEN      -- netmask length (often unset)
#* INTERNAL_IP4_NETADDR         -- address of network (only present if netmask is set)
#* INTERNAL_IP4_DNS             -- list of dns servers
#* INTERNAL_IP4_NBNS            -- list of wins servers
#* INTERNAL_IP6_ADDRESS         -- IPv6 address
#* INTERNAL_IP6_NETMASK         -- IPv6 netmask
#* INTERNAL_IP6_DNS             -- IPv6 list of dns servers
#* CISCO_DEF_DOMAIN             -- default domain name
#* CISCO_BANNER                 -- banner from server
#* CISCO_SPLIT_INC              -- number of networks in split-network-list
#* CISCO_SPLIT_INC_%d_ADDR      -- network address
#* CISCO_SPLIT_INC_%d_MASK      -- subnet mask (for example: 255.255.255.0)
#* CISCO_SPLIT_INC_%d_MASKLEN   -- subnet masklen (for example: 24)
#* CISCO_SPLIT_INC_%d_PROTOCOL  -- protocol (often just 0)
#* CISCO_SPLIT_INC_%d_SPORT     -- source port (often just 0)
#* CISCO_SPLIT_INC_%d_DPORT     -- destination port (often just 0)
#* CISCO_IPV6_SPLIT_INC         -- number of networks in IPv6 split-network-list
#* CISCO_IPV6_SPLIT_INC_%d_ADDR -- IPv6 network address
#* CISCO_IPV6_SPLIT_INC_$%d_MASKLEN -- IPv6 subnet masklen

# FIXMEs:

# Section A: route handling

# 1) The 3 values CISCO_SPLIT_INC_%d_PROTOCOL/SPORT/DPORT are currently being ignored
#   In order to use them, we'll probably need os specific solutions
#   * Linux: iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING <conditions> -j ROUTE --oif $TUNDEV
#       This would be an *alternative* to changing the routes (and thus 2) and 3)
#       shouldn't be relevant at all)
# 2) There are two different functions to set routes: generic routes and the
#   default route. Why isn't the defaultroute handled via the generic route case?
# 3) In the split tunnel case, all routes but the default route might get replaced
#   without getting restored later. We should explicitely check and save them just
#   like the defaultroute
# 4) Replies to a dhcp-server should never be sent into the tunnel

# Section B: Split DNS handling

# 1) Maybe dnsmasq can do something like that
# 2) Parse dns packets going out via tunnel and redirect them to original dns-server

#env | sort
#set -x

# =========== script (variable) setup ====================================

PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:$PATH

OS="`uname -s`"

HOOKS_DIR=/etc/vpnc
DEFAULT_ROUTE_FILE=/var/run/vpnc/defaultroute
RESOLV_CONF_BACKUP=/var/run/vpnc/resolv.conf-backup
SCRIPTNAME=`basename $0`

# some systems, eg. Darwin & FreeBSD, prune /var/run on boot
if [ ! -d "/var/run/vpnc" ]; then
    mkdir -p /var/run/vpnc
    [ -x /sbin/restorecon ] && /sbin/restorecon /var/run/vpnc
fi

# stupid SunOS: no blubber in /usr/local/bin ... (on stdout)
IPROUTE="`which ip | grep '^/'`" 2> /dev/null

if ifconfig --help 2>&1 | grep BusyBox > /dev/null; then
    ifconfig_syntax_inet=""
else
    ifconfig_syntax_inet="inet"
fi

if [ "$OS" = "Linux" ]; then
    ifconfig_syntax_ptp="pointopoint"
    route_syntax_gw="gw"
    route_syntax_del="del"
    route_syntax_netmask="netmask"
else
    ifconfig_syntax_ptp=""
    route_syntax_gw=""
    route_syntax_del="delete"
    route_syntax_netmask="-netmask"
fi
if [ "$OS" = "SunOS" ]; then
    route_syntax_interface="-interface"
    ifconfig_syntax_ptpv6="$INTERNAL_IP6_ADDRESS"
else
    route_syntax_interface=""
    ifconfig_syntax_ptpv6=""
fi

if [ -r /etc/openwrt_release ] && [ -n "$OPENWRT_INTERFACE" ]; then
        . /etc/functions.sh
    include /lib/network
    MODIFYRESOLVCONF=modify_resolvconf_openwrt
    RESTORERESOLVCONF=restore_resolvconf_openwrt
elif [ -x /sbin/resolvconf ]; then # Optional tool on Debian, Ubuntu, Gentoo
    MODIFYRESOLVCONF=modify_resolvconf_manager
    RESTORERESOLVCONF=restore_resolvconf_manager
elif [ -x /sbin/netconfig ]; then # tool on Suse after 11.1
    MODIFYRESOLVCONF=modify_resolvconf_suse_netconfig
    RESTORERESOLVCONF=restore_resolvconf_suse_netconfig
elif [ -x /sbin/modify_resolvconf ]; then # Mandatory tool on Suse earlier than 11.1
    MODIFYRESOLVCONF=modify_resolvconf_suse
    RESTORERESOLVCONF=restore_resolvconf_suse
else # Generic for any OS
    MODIFYRESOLVCONF=modify_resolvconf_generic
    RESTORERESOLVCONF=restore_resolvconf_generic
fi


# =========== script hooks =================================================

run_hooks() {
    HOOK="$1"

    if [ -d ${HOOKS_DIR}/${HOOK}.d ]; then
        for script in ${HOOKS_DIR}/${HOOK}.d/* ; do
        [ -f $script ] && . $script
        done
    fi
}

# =========== tunnel interface handling ====================================

do_ifconfig() {
    if [ -n "$INTERNAL_IP4_MTU" ]; then
        MTU=$INTERNAL_IP4_MTU
    elif [ -n "$IPROUTE" ]; then
        MTUDEV=`$IPROUTE route get "$VPNGATEWAY" | sed -ne 's/^.*dev \([a-z0-9]*\).*$/\1/p'`
        MTU=`$IPROUTE link show "$MTUDEV" | sed -ne 's/^.*mtu \([[:digit:]]\+\).*$/\1/p'`
        if [ -n "$MTU" ]; then
            MTU=`expr $MTU - 88`
        fi
    fi

    if [ -z "$MTU" ]; then
        MTU=1412
    fi

    # Point to point interface require a netmask of 255.255.255.255 on some systems
    if [ -n "$IPROUTE" ]; then
        $IPROUTE link set dev "$TUNDEV" up mtu "$MTU"
        $IPROUTE addr add "$INTERNAL_IP4_ADDRESS/255.255.255.255" peer "$INTERNAL_IP4_ADDRESS" dev "$TUNDEV"
    else
        ifconfig "$TUNDEV" ${ifconfig_syntax_inet} "$INTERNAL_IP4_ADDRESS" $ifconfig_syntax_ptp "$INTERNAL_IP4_ADDRESS" netmask 255.255.255.255 mtu ${MTU} up
    fi

    if [ -n "$INTERNAL_IP4_NETMASK" ]; then
        set_network_route $INTERNAL_IP4_NETADDR $INTERNAL_IP4_NETMASK $INTERNAL_IP4_NETMASKLEN
    fi

    # If the netmask is provided, it contains the address _and_ netmask
    if [ -n "$INTERNAL_IP6_ADDRESS" ] && [ -z "$INTERNAL_IP6_NETMASK" ]; then
        INTERNAL_IP6_NETMASK="$INTERNAL_IP6_ADDRESS/128"
    fi
    if [ -n "$INTERNAL_IP6_NETMASK" ]; then
        if [ -n "$IPROUTE" ]; then
        $IPROUTE -6 addr add $INTERNAL_IP6_NETMASK dev $TUNDEV
        else
        # Unlike for Legacy IP, we don't specify the dest_address
        # here on *BSD. OpenBSD for one will refuse to accept
        # incoming packets to that address if we do.
        # OpenVPN does the same (gives dest_address for Legacy IP
        # but not for IPv6).
        # Only Solaris needs it; hence $ifconfig_syntax_ptpv6
            ifconfig "$TUNDEV" inet6 $INTERNAL_IP6_NETMASK $ifconfig_syntax_ptpv6 mtu $MTU up
        fi
    fi
}

destroy_tun_device() {
    case "$OS" in
    NetBSD|FreeBSD) # and probably others...
        ifconfig "$TUNDEV" destroy
        ;;
    esac
}

# =========== route handling ====================================

if [ -n "$IPROUTE" ]; then
    fix_ip_get_output () {
        sed -e 's/ /\n/g' | \
            sed -ne '1p;/via/{N;p};/dev/{N;p};/src/{N;p};/mtu/{N;p}'
    }

    set_vpngateway_route() {
        $IPROUTE route add `$IPROUTE route get "$VPNGATEWAY" | fix_ip_get_output`
        $IPROUTE route flush cache
    }

    del_vpngateway_route() {
        $IPROUTE route $route_syntax_del "$VPNGATEWAY"
        $IPROUTE route flush cache
    }

    set_default_route() {
        $IPROUTE route | grep '^default' | fix_ip_get_output > "$DEFAULT_ROUTE_FILE"
        $IPROUTE route replace default dev "$TUNDEV"
        $IPROUTE route flush cache
    }

    set_network_route() {
        NETWORK="$1"
        NETMASK="$2"
        NETMASKLEN="$3"
        $IPROUTE route replace "$NETWORK/$NETMASKLEN" dev "$TUNDEV"
        $IPROUTE route flush cache
    }

    reset_default_route() {
        if [ -s "$DEFAULT_ROUTE_FILE" ]; then
            $IPROUTE route replace `cat "$DEFAULT_ROUTE_FILE"`
            $IPROUTE route flush cache
            rm -f -- "$DEFAULT_ROUTE_FILE"
        fi
    }

    del_network_route() {
        NETWORK="$1"
        NETMASK="$2"
        NETMASKLEN="$3"
        $IPROUTE route $route_syntax_del "$NETWORK/$NETMASKLEN" dev "$TUNDEV"
        $IPROUTE route flush cache
    }

    set_ipv6_default_route() {
        # We don't save/restore IPv6 default route; just add a higher-priority one.
        $IPROUTE -6 route add default dev "$TUNDEV" metric 1
        $IPROUTE -6 route flush cache
    }

    set_ipv6_network_route() {
        NETWORK="$1"
        NETMASKLEN="$2"
        $IPROUTE -6 route replace "$NETWORK/$NETMASKLEN" dev "$TUNDEV"
        $IPROUTE route flush cache
    }

    reset_ipv6_default_route() {
        $IPROUTE -6 route del default dev "$TUNDEV"
        $IPROUTE route flush cache
    }

    del_ipv6_network_route() {
        NETWORK="$1"
        NETMASKLEN="$2"
        $IPROUTE -6 route del "$NETWORK/$NETMASKLEN" dev "$TUNDEV"
        $IPROUTE -6 route flush cache
    }
else # use route command
    get_default_gw() {
        # isn't -n supposed to give --numeric output?
        # apperently not...
        # Get rid of lines containing IPv6 addresses (':')
        netstat -r -n | awk '/:/ { next; } /^(default|0\.0\.0\.0)/ { print $2; }'
    }

    set_vpngateway_route() {
        route add -host "$VPNGATEWAY" $route_syntax_gw "`get_default_gw`"
    }

    del_vpngateway_route() {
        route $route_syntax_del -host "$VPNGATEWAY" $route_syntax_gw "`get_default_gw`"
    }

    set_default_route() {
        DEFAULTGW="`get_default_gw`"
        echo "$DEFAULTGW" > "$DEFAULT_ROUTE_FILE"
        route $route_syntax_del default $route_syntax_gw "$DEFAULTGW"
        route add default $route_syntax_gw "$INTERNAL_IP4_ADDRESS" $route_syntax_interface
    }

    set_network_route() {
        NETWORK="$1"
        NETMASK="$2"
        NETMASKLEN="$3"
        del_network_route "$NETWORK" "$NETMASK" "$NETMASKLEN"
        route add -net "$NETWORK" $route_syntax_netmask "$NETMASK" $route_syntax_gw "$INTERNAL_IP4_ADDRESS" $route_syntax_interface
    }

    reset_default_route() {
        if [ -s "$DEFAULT_ROUTE_FILE" ]; then
            route $route_syntax_del default $route_syntax_gw "`get_default_gw`" $route_syntax_interface
            route add default $route_syntax_gw `cat "$DEFAULT_ROUTE_FILE"`
            rm -f -- "$DEFAULT_ROUTE_FILE"
        fi
    }

    del_network_route() {
        case "$OS" in
        Linux|NetBSD|Darwin|SunOS) # and probably others...
            # routes are deleted automatically on device shutdown
            return
            ;;
        esac
        NETWORK="$1"
        NETMASK="$2"
        NETMASKLEN="$3"
        route $route_syntax_del -net "$NETWORK" $route_syntax_netmask "$NETMASK" $route_syntax_gw "$INTERNAL_IP4_ADDRESS"
    }

    set_ipv6_default_route() {
        route add -inet6 default "$INTERNAL_IP6_ADDRESS" $route_syntax_interface
    }

    set_ipv6_network_route() {
        NETWORK="$1"
        NETMASK="$2"
        route add -inet6 -net "$NETWORK/$NETMASK" "$INTERNAL_IP6_ADDRESS" $route_syntax_interface
        :
    }

    reset_ipv6_default_route() {
        route $route_syntax_del -inet6 default "$INTERNAL_IP6_ADDRESS"
        :
    }

    del_ipv6_network_route() {
        NETWORK="$1"
        NETMASK="$2"
        route $route_syntax_del -inet6 "$NETWORK/$NETMASK" "$INTERNAL_IP6_ADDRESS"
        :
    }

fi

# =========== resolv.conf handling ====================================

# =========== resolv.conf handling for any OS =========================

modify_resolvconf_generic() {
    grep '^#@VPNC_GENERATED@' /etc/resolv.conf > /dev/null 2>&1 || cp -- /etc/resolv.conf "$RESOLV_CONF_BACKUP"
    NEW_RESOLVCONF="#@VPNC_GENERATED@ -- this file is generated by vpnc
# and will be overwritten by vpnc
# as long as the above mark is intact"

    # Remember the original value of CISCO_DEF_DOMAIN we need it later
    CISCO_DEF_DOMAIN_ORIG="$CISCO_DEF_DOMAIN"
    # Don't step on INTERNAL_IP4_DNS value, use a temporary variable
    INTERNAL_IP4_DNS_TEMP="$INTERNAL_IP4_DNS"
    exec 6< "$RESOLV_CONF_BACKUP"
    while read LINE <&6 ; do
        case "$LINE" in
            nameserver*)
                if [ -n "$INTERNAL_IP4_DNS_TEMP" ]; then
                    read ONE_NAMESERVER INTERNAL_IP4_DNS_TEMP <<-EOF
    $INTERNAL_IP4_DNS_TEMP
EOF
                    LINE="nameserver $ONE_NAMESERVER"
                else
                    LINE=""
                fi
                ;;
            search*)
                if [ -n "$CISCO_DEF_DOMAIN" ]; then
                    LINE="$LINE $CISCO_DEF_DOMAIN"
                    CISCO_DEF_DOMAIN=""
                fi
                ;;
            domain*)
                if [ -n "$CISCO_DEF_DOMAIN" ]; then
                    LINE="domain $CISCO_DEF_DOMAIN"
                    CISCO_DEF_DOMAIN=""
                fi
                ;;
        esac
        NEW_RESOLVCONF="$NEW_RESOLVCONF
$LINE"
    done
    exec 6<&-

    for i in $INTERNAL_IP4_DNS_TEMP ; do
        NEW_RESOLVCONF="$NEW_RESOLVCONF
nameserver $i"
    done
    if [ -n "$CISCO_DEF_DOMAIN" ]; then
        NEW_RESOLVCONF="$NEW_RESOLVCONF
search $CISCO_DEF_DOMAIN"
    fi
    echo "$NEW_RESOLVCONF" > /etc/resolv.conf

    if [ "$OS" = "Darwin" ]; then
        case "`uname -r`" in
            # Skip for pre-10.4 systems
            4.*|5.*|6.*|7.*)
                ;;
            # 10.4 and later require use of scutil for DNS to work properly
            *)
                OVERRIDE_PRIMARY=""
                if [ -n "$CISCO_SPLIT_INC" ]; then
                    if [ $CISCO_SPLIT_INC -lt 1 ]; then
                        # Must override for correct default route
                        # Cannot use multiple DNS matching in this case
                        OVERRIDE_PRIMARY='d.add OverridePrimary # 1'
                    fi
                fi
                # Uncomment the following if/fi pair to use multiple
                # DNS matching when available.  When multiple DNS matching
                # is present, anything reading the /etc/resolv.conf file
                # directly will probably not work as intended.
                #if [ -z "$CISCO_DEF_DOMAIN_ORIG" ]; then
                    # Cannot use multiple DNS matching without a domain
                    OVERRIDE_PRIMARY='d.add OverridePrimary # 1'
                #fi
                scutil >/dev/null 2>&1 <<-EOF
                    open
                    d.init
                    d.add ServerAddresses * $INTERNAL_IP4_DNS
                    set State:/Network/Service/$TUNDEV/DNS
                    d.init
                    # next line overrides the default gateway and breaks split routing
                    # d.add Router $INTERNAL_IP4_ADDRESS
                    d.add Addresses * $INTERNAL_IP4_ADDRESS
                    d.add SubnetMasks * 255.255.255.255
                    d.add InterfaceName $TUNDEV
                    $OVERRIDE_PRIMARY
                    set State:/Network/Service/$TUNDEV/IPv4
                    close
                EOF
                if [ -n "$CISCO_DEF_DOMAIN_ORIG" ]; then
                    scutil >/dev/null 2>&1 <<-EOF
                        open
                        get State:/Network/Service/$TUNDEV/DNS
                        d.add DomainName $CISCO_DEF_DOMAIN_ORIG
                        d.add SearchDomains * $CISCO_DEF_DOMAIN_ORIG
                        d.add SupplementalMatchDomains * $CISCO_DEF_DOMAIN_ORIG
                        set State:/Network/Service/$TUNDEV/DNS
                        close
                    EOF
                fi
                ;;
        esac
    fi
}

restore_resolvconf_generic() {
    if [ ! -f "$RESOLV_CONF_BACKUP" ]; then
        return
    fi
    grep '^#@VPNC_GENERATED@' /etc/resolv.conf > /dev/null 2>&1 && cat "$RESOLV_CONF_BACKUP" > /etc/resolv.conf
    rm -f -- "$RESOLV_CONF_BACKUP"

    if [ "$OS" = "Darwin" ]; then
        case "`uname -r`" in
            # Skip for pre-10.4 systems
            4.*|5.*|6.*|7.*)
                ;;
            # 10.4 and later require use of scutil for DNS to work properly
            *)
                scutil >/dev/null 2>&1 <<-EOF
                    open
                    remove State:/Network/Service/$TUNDEV/IPv4
                    remove State:/Network/Service/$TUNDEV/DNS
                    close
                EOF
                ;;
        esac
    fi
}
# === resolv.conf handling via /sbin/netconfig (Suse 11.1) =====================

# Suse provides a script that modifies resolv.conf. Use it because it will
# restart/reload all other services that care about it (e.g. lwresd).  [unclear if this is still true, but probably --mlk]

modify_resolvconf_suse_netconfig()
{
    /sbin/netconfig modify -s vpnc -i "$TUNDEV" <<-EOF
        INTERFACE='$TUNDEV'
        DNSSERVERS='$INTERNAL_IP4_DNS'
        DNSDOMAIN='$CISCO_DEF_DOMAIN'
        EOF
}
# Restore resolv.conf to old contents on Suse
restore_resolvconf_suse_netconfig()
{
    /sbin/netconfig remove -s vpnc -i "$TUNDEV"
}

# === resolv.conf handling via /sbin/modify_resolvconf (Suse) =====================

# Suse provides a script that modifies resolv.conf. Use it because it will
# restart/reload all other services that care about it (e.g. lwresd).

modify_resolvconf_suse()
{
    FULL_SCRIPTNAME=`readlink -f $0`
    RESOLV_OPTS=''
    test -n "$INTERNAL_IP4_DNS" && RESOLV_OPTS="-n \"$INTERNAL_IP4_DNS\""
    test -n "$CISCO_DEF_DOMAIN" && RESOLV_OPTS="$RESOLV_OPTS -d $CISCO_DEF_DOMAIN"
    test -n "$RESOLV_OPTS" && eval /sbin/modify_resolvconf modify -s vpnc -p $SCRIPTNAME -f $FULL_SCRIPTNAME -e $TUNDEV $RESOLV_OPTS -t \"This file was created by $SCRIPTNAME\"
}

# Restore resolv.conf to old contents on Suse
restore_resolvconf_suse()
{
    FULL_SCRIPTNAME=`readlink -f $0`
    /sbin/modify_resolvconf restore -s vpnc -p $SCRIPTNAME -f $FULL_SCRIPTNAME -e $TUNDEV
}

# === resolv.conf handling via UCI (OpenWRT) =========

modify_resolvconf_openwrt() {
    add_dns $OPENWRT_INTERFACE $INTERNAL_IP4_DNS
}

restore_resolvconf_openwrt() {
    remove_dns $OPENWRT_INTERFACE
}
# === resolv.conf handling via /sbin/resolvconf (Debian, Ubuntu, Gentoo)) =========

modify_resolvconf_manager() {
    NEW_RESOLVCONF=""
    for i in $INTERNAL_IP4_DNS; do
        NEW_RESOLVCONF="$NEW_RESOLVCONF
nameserver $i"
    done
    if [ -n "$CISCO_DEF_DOMAIN" ]; then
        NEW_RESOLVCONF="$NEW_RESOLVCONF
domain $CISCO_DEF_DOMAIN"
    fi
    echo "$NEW_RESOLVCONF" | /sbin/resolvconf -a $TUNDEV
}

restore_resolvconf_manager() {
    /sbin/resolvconf -d $TUNDEV
}

# ========= Toplevel state handling  =======================================

kernel_is_2_6_or_above() {
    case `uname -r` in
        1.*|2.[012345]*)
            return 1
            ;;
        *)
            return 0
            ;;
    esac
}

do_pre_init() {
    if [ "$OS" = "Linux" ]; then
        if (exec 6<> /dev/net/tun) > /dev/null 2>&1 ; then
            :
        else # can't open /dev/net/tun
            test -e /proc/sys/kernel/modprobe && `cat /proc/sys/kernel/modprobe` tun 2>/dev/null
            # fix for broken devfs in kernel 2.6.x
            if [ "`readlink /dev/net/tun`" = misc/net/tun \
                -a ! -e /dev/net/misc/net/tun -a -e /dev/misc/net/tun ] ; then
                ln -sf /dev/misc/net/tun /dev/net/tun
            fi
            # make sure tun device exists
            if [ ! -e /dev/net/tun ]; then
                mkdir -p /dev/net
                mknod -m 0640 /dev/net/tun c 10 200
                [ -x /sbin/restorecon ] && /sbin/restorecon /dev/net/tun
            fi
            # workaround for a possible latency caused by udev, sleep max. 10s
            if kernel_is_2_6_or_above ; then
                for x in `seq 100` ; do
                    (exec 6<> /dev/net/tun) > /dev/null 2>&1 && break;
                    sleep 0.1
                done
            fi
        fi
    elif [ "$OS" = "FreeBSD" ]; then
        if [ ! -e /dev/tun ]; then
            kldload if_tun
        fi
    elif [ "$OS" = "GNU/kFreeBSD" ]; then
        if [ ! -e /dev/tun ]; then
            kldload if_tun
        fi
    elif [ "$OS" = "NetBSD" ]; then
        :
    elif [ "$OS" = "OpenBSD" ]; then
        :
    elif [ "$OS" = "SunOS" ]; then
        :
    elif [ "$OS" = "Darwin" ]; then
        :
    fi
}

do_connect() {
    if [ -n "$CISCO_BANNER" ]; then
        echo "Connect Banner:"
        echo "$CISCO_BANNER" | while read LINE ; do echo "|" "$LINE" ; done
        echo
    fi

    set_vpngateway_route
    do_ifconfig
    if [ -n "$CISCO_SPLIT_INC" ]; then
        i=0
        while [ $i -lt $CISCO_SPLIT_INC ] ; do
            eval NETWORK="\${CISCO_SPLIT_INC_${i}_ADDR}"
            eval NETMASK="\${CISCO_SPLIT_INC_${i}_MASK}"
            eval NETMASKLEN="\${CISCO_SPLIT_INC_${i}_MASKLEN}"
            if [ $NETWORK != "0.0.0.0" ]; then
                set_network_route "$NETWORK" "$NETMASK" "$NETMASKLEN"
            else
                set_default_route
            fi
            i=`expr $i + 1`
        done
        for i in $INTERNAL_IP4_DNS ; do
            echo "$i" | grep : >/dev/null || \
                set_network_route "$i" "255.255.255.255" "32"
        done
    elif [ -n "$INTERNAL_IP4_ADDRESS" ]; then
        set_default_route
    fi
    if [ -n "$CISCO_IPV6_SPLIT_INC" ]; then
        i=0
        while [ $i -lt $CISCO_IPV6_SPLIT_INC ] ; do
            eval NETWORK="\${CISCO_IPV6_SPLIT_INC_${i}_ADDR}"
            eval NETMASKLEN="\${CISCO_IPV6_SPLIT_INC_${i}_MASKLEN}"
            if [ $NETMASKLEN -lt 128 ]; then
                set_ipv6_network_route "$NETWORK" "$NETMASKLEN"
            else
                set_ipv6_default_route
            fi
            i=`expr $i + 1`
        done
        for i in $INTERNAL_IP4_DNS ; do
            if echo "$i" | grep : >/dev/null; then
                set_ipv6_network_route "$i" "128"
            fi
        done
    elif [ -n "$INTERNAL_IP6_NETMASK" -o -n "$INTERNAL_IP6_ADDRESS" ]; then
        set_ipv6_default_route
    fi

    if [ -n "$INTERNAL_IP4_DNS" ]; then
        $MODIFYRESOLVCONF
    fi
}

do_disconnect() {
    if [ -n "$CISCO_SPLIT_INC" ]; then
        i=0
        while [ $i -lt $CISCO_SPLIT_INC ] ; do
            eval NETWORK="\${CISCO_SPLIT_INC_${i}_ADDR}"
            eval NETMASK="\${CISCO_SPLIT_INC_${i}_MASK}"
            eval NETMASKLEN="\${CISCO_SPLIT_INC_${i}_MASKLEN}"
            if [ $NETWORK != "0.0.0.0" ]; then
                # FIXME: This doesn't restore previously overwritten
                #        routes.
                del_network_route "$NETWORK" "$NETMASK" "$NETMASKLEN"
            else
                reset_default_route
            fi
            i=`expr $i + 1`
        done
        for i in $INTERNAL_IP4_DNS ; do
            del_network_route "$i" "255.255.255.255" "32"
        done
    else
        reset_default_route
    fi
    if [ -n "$CISCO_IPV6_SPLIT_INC" ]; then
        i=0
        while [ $i -lt $CISCO_IPV6_SPLIT_INC ] ; do
            eval NETWORK="\${CISCO_IPV6_SPLIT_INC_${i}_ADDR}"
            eval NETMASKLEN="\${CISCO_IPV6_SPLIT_INC_${i}_MASKLEN}"
            if [ $NETMASKLEN -eq 0 ]; then
                reset_ipv6_default_route
            else
                del_ipv6_network_route "$NETWORK" "$NETMASKLEN"
            fi
            i=`expr $i + 1`
        done
        for i in $INTERNAL_IP6_DNS ; do
            del_ipv6_network_route "$i" "128"
        done
    elif [ -n "$INTERNAL_IP6_NETMASK" -o -n "$INTERNAL_IP6_ADDRESS" ]; then
        reset_ipv6_default_route
    fi

    del_vpngateway_route

    if [ -n "$INTERNAL_IP4_DNS" ]; then
        $RESTORERESOLVCONF
    fi
    destroy_tun_device
}

#### Main

if [ -z "$reason" ]; then
    echo "this script must be called from vpnc" 1>&2
    exit 1
fi

case "$reason" in
    pre-init)
        run_hooks pre-init
        do_pre_init
        ;;
    connect)
        run_hooks connect
        do_connect
        run_hooks post-connect
        ;;
    disconnect)
        run_hooks disconnect
        do_disconnect
        run_hooks post-disconnect
        ;;
    reconnect)
        run_hooks reconnect
        ;;
    *)
        echo "unknown reason '$reason'. Maybe vpnc-script is out of date" 1>&2
        exit 1
        ;;
esac

exit 0
****************************************************************************************
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your heredocs (e.g. `scutil >/dev/null 2>&1 <<-EOF`) are unterminated. When you use `<<-` you can only indent the terminator with tabs.

From `man bash` (version 5.0.18)

> This type of redirection instructs the shell to read input from the
> current source until a line containing only delimiter (with no
> trailing blanks) is seen.

...

> If the redirection operator is <<-, then
> all leading tab characters are stripped from input lines and the line
> containing delimiter.

Combine those together, and << requires the terminator to be completely unprefixed, while <<- allows tabs to prefix the terminator.

Answer (score 1):

The HereDoc Delimiter must be placed at the beginning of the a line:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

hello() {
    cat <<-EOF
    Hallo There
EOF
}

hello()
```

instead of:

```
#!/bin/bash

hello() {
    cat <<-EOF
    Hallo There
    EOF
}

hello
```

which results in:

```
./test.sh: line 9: warning: here-document at line 4 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
./test.sh: line 10: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: how are you supposed to see the tabs?